# Upload Files to Documentset with MS Graph Rest APi

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to figure out how to upload files to a document set.
It uses Lists,
for upload files to a drive, it works following the manual i found on learn.microsoft.com

- this is my case.
  for each order i a documenset created by ms graph rest API.
  when files added to the order they must be uploaded to the document set.

'''
Already working

- Upload Files to a drive
- To a List - create folder - change to custom documentset
  Not working - or cant figured out.
  Upload file in create documentset.
  '''

But how or and how are they stored in SharePoint.
, for each drive, i get a drive id,
for each document in, does have them the same listid or?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

When you need to find out the relation between ListItems or DriveItems, just add - Driveitem after the listId. Then you wil get the DriveID.
In the same way, it works for getting to know the listId - add DriveaId of the ListID.

Now I can add the correct file to the correct documentset(folder).

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue but have already added the DriveID and list ID. I can enumerate entities in a list and a drive. I can create folders but cannot seem to upload a file (both simple and UploadSession methods fail. Simple (small file) uploads indicate that the request requires a JSON body. For endpoint /me/root:filename.jpeg/content' it works fine ->upload($fileURI) !!! but for Sites/List/Drive it does not and complains of JSON body.
-- For UploadSession I get an 'ItemNotFound' error when attempting to initiate the session... (Using delegated token method atm)

Comment: ANSWER - Endpoint required a / before the filename.. TIPS: Check permissions and custom endpoint with correct suffix (e.g. createUploadSession, content etc), check slashes and colons are correctly positioned